# How to make images as buttons in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to put some images in my website with enabling the ability to click on these images. I was using MapEdit software before but now I am looking for a simple method rather than image mapping, so could you please provide me with the simplest tools and ways for doing that.

Comment: Just wrap your images inside link tags: `<a href="#"><img src="" /></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 simpliest solutions.

1.Put your image into  tag like this

```
<a href="..."><img>...</img></a>
```

2.Write javascript function for image click

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty straightforward. An image inside of a link:

```
<a href="/foo/bar.html">
  <img src="foo.png" alt="A Foobar, roaming in its natural territory." />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want forms try:

```
<form name="myform" action="path/to/something.php" method="POST">
<input type="image" src="myImage.png" name="myname" width="60" height="60">
</form>
```